# How to compare T-SQL codes with SSMS, is there a function?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a SQL code and I want to see differences to a older version

Is there a function in the SSMS that help compare a T-SQL code?

Comment: "compare a T-SQL code", can you explain more about what you intend to do here?

Comment: I have a SQL code and I want to see differences to a older version

Comment: No SSMS has no such function. Your source control system (hint) does.

Comment: Not unless you want to do restore of the database to a different DB and then do it that way.

Comment: Version of what?

Comment: @shawnt00 versions of the sql source codes